# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when i am trying to append this to a dynamically created tab

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append the data to a dynamically created tab where x is a variable having data but it is not appending. Can any one help me as i am new to javascript.

```
$("#abc").append('<div id="'+month+'" class="tabcontent"><div id='December"+month+"'>"+x+"</div></div>');
```

Comment: Check your code more thoroughly. If you're already coding this far (" append the data to a dynamically created tab"), you should know how to solve such simple syntax errors. Even the code highlighting above indicates to you where the syntax went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly appending strings there.

The valid syntax would be:

```
'<div id="'+month+'" class="tabcontent"><div id="December'+month+'">'+x+'</div></div>'
```

Here are the problems in original code:

```
$("#abc").append('<div id="'+month+'" class="tabcontent"><div id='December"+month+"'>"+x+"</div></div>');
//                                                               ^.......^.........^.^...^
```

Answer (score 0):

If x is variable and you want to append ' around it then ->
$("#abc").append("'"+x+"'");